# Correcting rotated molecule

Tags: chemfig

I use `chemfig` to draw cyclic molecules. Quite often, it is desirable to reorient the molecule for which I use the optional directive `[rotate=-18]`. Sometimes this is barely acceptable but most often just wrong.

How do I achieve the following -

1. The letters should not be rotated even if the molecule is.
2. The double bond should be rotated in its entirety.
3. The molecule should not be shifted upward or downward.

Or is there any way to achieve my objectives.

My MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    Unrotated & Rotated & \\
    \chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)} & \chemfig[][rotate=-30]{*6(-=-=-=)} & Acceptable\\
    \chemfig{*5(---O-(=[:145]O)-)} & \chemfig[][rotate=-55]{*5(---O-(=[:145]O)-)} & unacceptable \\
    \chemfig{*5(-N(-H)-=-=)} & \chemfig[][rotate=-18]{*5(-N(-H)-=-=)} & unacceptable
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: molecules]

Comment: Does this run through on your machine? (I am not implying you are doing something wrong but I get errors when I run this on my just updated TeXLive 2020 installation with `pdflatex`.) BTW, if I had to guess, I'd try `\chemfig[][rotate=-55,transform shape=false]{*5(---O-(=[:145]O)-)}` but this is just a guess.

Comment: It does run without any problem. I had already tried ``transform shape`` ... both ``true`` and ``false`` are no different.

I am using TeXLive 2019

Comment: BTW, I didn't find this ``rotate`` hack from docs. I just tried an ugly hack. I am not sure if it is supposed to work. Maybe TeXLive-2020 has explicitly barred it.

Comment: You did not yet tell me which compiler you are using and how old your installation is.

Comment: compiler = ``pdflatex``. July 2019 installation.

Comment: Just for the records, mine is `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)`. So one has to wait and see if users with an older installation can compile it (or I did something wrong). Of course, you could just update your installation, maybe the problem has meanwhile been solved.

Answer (score 2):

I have a partial answer. This takes care of my concern number 1 and 2. However the molecule is still shifted downwards probably because it is rotated w.r.t. the origin.

This time I am using a `()` outisde the ring and issuing a `[::-30]` directive just at the start of `()`.

[image]
Please see this MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
    Unrotated & Rotated & Rotated & \\
        & rotate=-30 hack & [::-30] hack \\
    \chemfig{*6(-=-=-=)} & \chemfig[][rotate=-30]{*6(-=-=-=)} & \chemfig{([::-30]*6(-=-=-=))} & Acceptable\\
    \chemfig{*5(---O-(=[:145]O)-)} & \chemfig[][rotate=-55]{*5(---O-(=[:145]O)-)} & \chemfig{([::-55]*5(---O-(=[:90]O)-))} & unacceptable \\
    \chemfig{*5(-N(-H)-=-=)} & \chemfig[][rotate=-18]{*5(-N(-H)-=-=)} & \chemfig{([::-18]*5(-N(-H)-=-=))} & unacceptable 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```